# File nodeWebkit on click on <input type="file"> going to back ground

Tags: html, angularjs, node-webkit

[screen shot link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kat3p95mdvffhgj/sr.png?dl=0)

I am using AngularJS in front end nodeWebkit 10.5 to run it like a desktop app.
  When i click on  the file browser pops up but goes to background.

I am also able to click the input button multiple times. When i click multiple times and then close the file-browser the file-browser opens again.

By default in chrome and nodewebkit one cannot access the app when the file browser is opened.

`<input type="file" id="fileInput" class="image-selector" name="image" accept="image/*" directive-enter='savePic($event)' /`>

As u can see in screenshot the file browser goes to background .
[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide a screen shot, or more code? Do you have a custom directive at play here? What is the question "How to stop a file browser from going to the background?"?

Comment: i have added a link where my screen shot where file browser is in background.

Comment: This is a Windows problem. Please, open a bug in the Hasefroch system. Maybe if you share more code we can view if is a windows problem or is a bug of your code

Comment: This is not windows problem i wrrote the same code in chrome and  nodewebkit ,  the file browser will be always focused and i cannot click on the app (browser or nodewebkit).

Comment: I think this is a nodewebkit issue I wrote the code just for n experiment this has the same problem .
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>   
      Select images: <input type="file" name="img">    
    </body>
 </html>